# CURL in PHP Code

Tags: joomla

i have developed a component and i need to make it secure as it should no longer be used for more than one URL for which the component has been purchased. Can it be done by PHP Curl code or any other way to make it restrict for users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , you can use

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , to check the referrer also pass a unique
>   key using CURL so you will get the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] + unique 
>   key throgh curl and if allowed process it ...

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
// you will get the referrer and please check using an IF clasuse
?>
```

Comment: any source file where i can see the fully demo ? Thanks for this help, i hope surely it will work for me.

Comment: @Nikita Chopra was it useful ? then consider upvoting :)